# Makefile default rule pattern

Tags: makefile, default, target, rules

Just trying to write a conditional Makefile using this skeleton:

```
TARGET = test

ifeq ($(FOO),y)

$(TARGET):
    @echo This is test
$(TARGET)-a:
    @echo This is test-a
$(TARGET)-b:
    @echo This is test-b

else
$(info FOO is disabled)
endif
```

When the FOO condition is true, the set of rules based on the TARGET variable (composed of one $(TARGET) and a set of $(TARGET)-substring) work as expected:

```
$ make test
This is test

$ make test-a
This is test-a
```

When the FOO condition is false, I want to define a default rule for all my targets, just to report on the screen FOO variable is disabled. I don't know the proper way to do that. Tried some options:

Option1, using the skeleton example, the string "FOO is disabled" is always printed, but it generates an error:

```
$ make test-a
FOO is disabled
make: *** No rule to make target 'test-a'.  Stop.

$ make test  
FOO is disabled
make: *** No rule to make target 'test'.  Stop.
```

Option 2, if try to modify the false rule in this way:

```
else
$(TARGET)-%:
    $(info FOO is disabled)
endif
```

Then all $(TARGET)-substring targets work as expected:

```
$ make test-a
FOO is disabled
make: 'test-a' is up to date.

$ make test-b
FOO is disabled
make: 'test-b' is up to date.
```

But this rule fails when making $(TARGET):

```
$ make test
make: *** No rule to make target 'test'.  Stop.
```

Option 3, if try to remove the hyphen on the false rule defined in option2:

```
else
$(TARGET)%:
    $(info FOO is disabled)
endif
```

then making $(TARGET) executes a default rule for compiling a test.o object file:

```
$ make test
FOO is disabled
cc   test.o   -o test
cc: error: test.o: No such file or directory
cc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
make: *** [<builtin>: test] Error 1
```

And I am becoming a little bit crazy trying so satisfy this default rule. Please some help with this would be very useful. Tnks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MadScientist says, .DEFAULT rule fixes the issue when you have a single Makefile. So this would be the final Makefile:

```
TARGET = test

ifeq ($(FOO),y)

$(TARGET):
    @echo This is test
$(TARGET)-a:
    @echo This is test-a
$(TARGET)-b:
    @echo This is test-b

endif

.DEFAULT:
    @echo This is the default rule
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to solve this, but the simplest is probably just to add another rule:

```
else

$(TARGET):
    @echo FOO is disabled

$(TARGET)%:
    @echo FOO is disabled

endif
```

(I changed `$(info ...` to `@echo ...` because the latter will run only when Make execute the rule, while the former will run if the conditional defines those rules, even if the target is something else.)

**EDIT:** Yes, it's possible to solve this with only one rule, there is more than one way, but no perfect way.

Here is one way:

```
TARGET = tes

...

else

$(TARGET)%:
    @echo FOO is disabled

endif
```

Note that the last character of `test` has been removed. The good news is that this rule will apply to `test`, `test-a` and `test-b`; the bad news is that it will also apply to `tesw`.

Comment: Remove the `%` from `$(TARGET)%`.  It doesn't help to have it here because `%` must match at least one character.  It can't match no characters.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes that solves my issue, but do you think is possible to fix this issue with just one rule?

Comment: @MadScientist: Yes, I know, that's the whole point, that's why I added a rule. And if I removed the `%`, my makefile wouldn't work.

Comment: Oh sorry I misread your answer I thought the first one was `$(TARGET)-%`.  My bad!

Comment: @alcastell You can use the `.DEFAULT` target instead; see https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Last-Resort.html

Comment: @MadScientist, this is exactly what I was looking for. Please, answer my question with this content and I will accept you answer as the valid answer to this issue. Thanks a lot, this was very helpful!